# Syntax Error near Insert Statement

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to insert data in Access database but getting a `Syntax error` exception :( What am I doing wrong ?

```
Private Sub savebtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles savebtn.Click
    Dim con As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\vb8\Mini-project\Mini-project\mini_db.mdb")
    Dim query As String
    Try
        con.Open()
        query = "INSERT INTO minitab VALUES (" & TextBox1.Text & "," & TextBox2.Text & ",@dob ," & TextBox5.Text & "," & TextBox6.Text & "," & TextBox7.Text & "," & TextBox8.Text & "," & TextBox9.Text & ")"
        Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(query, con)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
        MsgBox("Data has been saved", MsgBoxStyle.SystemModal, "ok")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Learn how to use parameters. Do not take the user inputs to build an sql command text. Probably your problem is caused by a single quote present in one of your textboxes. But do not try to fix it with some kind of string replacement. That won't help you in Sql Injection attacks. Just use parameters.

Comment: `What am I doing wrong ?` A) did not read [ask] and take the [tour] b) did not give the complete error message (those usually have a 'near ...' part to them to tell you where the error is) c) concatenating values and strings to make SQL d) not disposing of your DB objects e) Not researching the [proper SQL syntax](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/index.htm) before using it in code

Comment: The very first thing you're doing wrong is that you were told that there's a syntax error in your `INSERT` statement and yet you haven't bothered to actually look at your `INSERT` statement. There are other issues here too but that should be the most obvious. If you're told that there's an issue somewhere, actually look where you're told the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding values in your `Insert` statement without addressing the columns. Now, this is not necessary if you put the values in the correct order so I suggest you to check it again. However, if you specify the column names then your insert statement might look like:

```
"INSERT INTO minitab(column1,Column2,Column3)VALUES(@col1,@col2,@col3)",connectiontring

cmd.Parameters.Add("@col1",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtBox1.Text  'make sure to set the datatype correctly
cmd.Parameters.Add("@col2",OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TxtBox2.Text
.........
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

And most importantly, what are you trying to do? If you are trying to insert data, then why are you using a `DataTable`? The code above will let you insert data into the database. However, a datatable is used to get data from the database and display it. Also `DataTable`s have change tracking and are used in conjunction with `DataAdapters` to perform CRUD operations.

However, to use a `DataTable` to display data, you can try this:

```
Dim cmd as new OleDbCommand("Select * from minitab",connectionstring)
Dim dt as new DataTable
Dim ada as new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
ada.Fill(dt)
```

To display the data, you can use various controls. One of them is a `DataGridView`.

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Hope you understand :)

Comment: While your answer looks like it'll solve the OP's problem, it adds a different problem as described in [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: Didn't know that :( . But edited my answer ...Make sure to to upvote it if it's useful :)

Comment: Also make sure to mark it as an answer if it helped Mr.OP

Comment: While you are correct regarding OP's misuse of the DataTable, they are not just for getting data from the database. DataTables have change tracking and are used in conjunction with DataAdapters to perform CRUD operations.

Comment: It is not necessary to specify the column names in an `INSERT` statement if you provide values for all columns in the correct order. If you don;t do that then you have an issue but the error message would be something other than about a syntax error, so that is not actually the OP's issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney,didn't know that column names weren't necessary :) Thanks for mentioning